# How do I access variables from app script code in html file and be able to print them in table?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have only started using apps script and finished my code. I want to be able to manipulate or iterate through the variables that I created in my code in my html file. how can I do this? is it the same way as for a spreadsheet? Thanks

These are my variables:

```
for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){

  var date1 = events[i].getStartTime();
  var date2 = events[i].getEndTime();
  var title = events[i].getTitle();
  var descript = events[i].getDescription();
  var site = events[i].getLocation();

  if(events[i+1].getStartTime() - events[i].getEndTime() < 2){

  var distance = Maps.newDirectionFinder().setAlternatives(true).setOrigin('Corner 3rd and 7th Avenues, Parktown North')
                 .addWaypoint(site).addWaypoint(events[i+2].getLocation())
                 .setDestination('Corner 3rd and 7th Avenues, Parktown North') //Finishes day at Head Office
                 .setMode(DRIVING).getDirections();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is called "templated html". Templates allow you to pass variables and call Apps Script functions from within your HTML file.

There are several approaches you could use to build your table, so best to read through the documentation and experiment until you find an option that makes sense to you.

See the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I managed to work with google.script.run. Just need to get my code to work properly.